# How to stop service even after restarting activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

I want to stop service from activity . It stops when i don't close the app . But when i close the app and run the app again service doesn't stop.

**Flow :**

--> Click Switch ON 
--> Show Notification / Location Listener 
--> Kill App 
--> Notification still remains (Service is running means) 
--> Open app again and 
--> Click Switch OFF 
--> Service doesn't stop and notification persists

**Service Class**

```
public class locationService extends Service {

NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
NotificationManager notificationManager;

public static final String serviceTag = "LocationServiceTag";


@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mBinder;
}

@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
    return super.onUnbind(intent);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("AppPref",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    userCurrentRoute= sharedPref.getString("RouteNo","");

    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent repeating_intent =new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent= PendingIntent.getActivity(this,10,repeating_intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


     builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.bus_small)
            .setContentTitle("BusBuzz")
            .setContentText("Sharing Location to all")
            .setAutoCancel(false)
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
            .setOngoing(true)
            ;

    notificationManager.notify(10,builder.build());

    provider = new LocationGooglePlayServicesProvider();
    provider.setCheckLocationSettings(true);

    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    notificationManager.cancel(10);
    Toast.makeText(this, "App Closed Location Sharing Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    SmartLocation.with(this).location().stop();
    super.onDestroy();
}

}
```

**Activity**

```
 if (isChecked) {

                startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,locationService.class).addCategory(locationService.serviceTag));

            }
            else
            {


                stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,locationService.class).addCategory(locationService.serviceTag));

            }
```

Comment: did you use anywhere  Timer concept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote:

```
--> Click Switch ON
--> Show Notification / Location Listener
--> Kill App
--> Notification still remains (Service is running means)
```

Just because the notification exists, **does not mean** that the `Service` is still running. Actually, it is dead. You killed the App, which kills the `Service`, and since you return `START_NOT_STICKY` from `onStartCommand()`, Android will not restart the `Service` until your App makes another explicit call to `startService()`. Since the App was killed, `onDestroy()` was never called, so the notification was never removed.

You can verify this by using `adb shell dumpsys activity services` to see if your `Service` is running after you kill your App.

Comment: Yeah i got it running using foreground service. Foreground service also accepts notification as argument . My approach was wrong earlier .